# PHP: preg_replace only first matching string in array

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, preg-split

I've started with preg_replace in PHP and I wonder how I can replace only first matching array key with a specified array value cause I set preg_replace number of changes parameter to '1' and it's changing more than one time anyways. I also splitted my string to single words and I'm examining them one by one:

```
<?php
  $internal_message = 'Hey, this is awesome!';

  $words = array(
     '/wesome(\W|$)/' => 'wful',
     '/wful(\W|$)/' => 'wesome',
     '/^this(\W|$)/' => 'that',
     '/^that(\W|$)/' => 'this'
  );

  $splitted_message = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $internal_message);
  $words_num = count($splitted_message);

  for($i=0; $i<$words_num; $i++) {
     $splitted_message[$i] = preg_replace(array_keys($words), array_values($words), $splitted_message[$i], 1);
  }

  $message = implode(" ", $splitted_message);
  echo $message;
?>
```

I want this to be on output:

> Hey, that is awful

(one suffix change, one word change and stops)

Not this:

> Hey, this is awesome

(two suffix changes, two word changes and back to original word & suffix...)

Maybe I can simplify this code? I also can't change order of the array keys and values cause there will be more suffixes and single words to change soon. I'm kinda newbie in php coding and I'll be thankful for any help ;>

Comment: Try [this approach](https://ideone.com/zoMVNI).

Comment: Nvrmind, works like charm! Thanks ;>

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew special characters are very important for me now and without them I won't be able to do anything with this code

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are working with Unicode texts from the very  beginning, it is an important detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use plain text in the associative array keys that you will use to create dynamic regex patterns from, and use `preg_replace_callback` to replace the found values with the replacements in one go.

```
$internal_message = 'Hey, this is awesome!';

$words = array(
    'wesome' => 'wful',
    'wful' => 'wesome',
    'this' => 'that',
    'that' => 'this'
);
$rx = '~(?:' . implode("|", array_keys($words)) . ')\b~';
echo "$rx\n";
$message = preg_replace_callback($rx, function($m) use ($words) {
    return isset($words[$m[0]]) ? $words[$m[0]] : $m[0];
}, $internal_message);
echo $message;
// => Hey, that is awful!
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/MQ1BTK).

The regex is

```
~(?:wesome|wful|this|that)\b~
```

The `(?:wesome|wful|this|that)` is a non-capturing group that matches any of the values inside, and `\b` is a word boundary, a non-consuming pattern that ensures there is no letter, digit or `_` after the suffix.

The `preg_replace_callback` parses the string once, and when a match occurs, it is passed to the anonymous function (`function($m)`) together with the `$words` array (`use ($words)`) and if the `$words` array contains the found key (`isset($words[$m[0]])`) the corresponding value is returned (`$words[$m[0]]`) or the found match is returned otherwise (`$m[0]`).

Comment: I have one more question, is there any option to work this with special characters like 'ś' or 'ć' at the end of the suffix? Cause i saw that suffixes with letters at the end like these are not being changed.

Comment: @ThatsJames Sure, just use the `u` modifier, `$rx = '~(?:' . implode("|", array_keys($words)) . ')\b~u';`

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry for not mentioning this detail earlier.